# Audio Streaming Server for PhoneGap App

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, audio-streaming

I am looking for a media server to help me deliver on demand mp3s to my clients via a phonegap app using phonegap media api. In my current solution it takes a while for larger files to load before it can start playing I want to lessen that time by using some sort of stream instead of doing direct download.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

past this into your config.xml file

```
 <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIBackgroundModes" overwrite="true">
    <array>
      <string>audio</string>
    </array>
  </gap:config-file>
```

Comment: When playing Audio it will tell iOS to keep the process running and not suspend it. So if you lock the screen or background the app . audio continues to play